# How can I create a pen drive that I can boot from, and then install Win98 from?

Tags: installation, boot, windows-98, usb-flash-drive

I have a HP Compaq t5515 thin client computer with a flash disk and USB port.  I want to put Win98 onto it, replacing whatever is on there now (I think it is some Linux-based thing).  I can find stuff about putting Win98 onto a pen drive and running from that, but I can't find any info about installing Windows 98 from a pen drive onto a sep[arate system.

Is it just a matter of

- making the pen drive bootable to DOS
- copying the contents of a Win98 installation CD onto the pen drive
- booting the HP machine from the pen drive
- running SETUP.EXE from the pen drive?

Any pointers appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Are you sure the thin client will boot from a usb device?

Comment: It will.  If I put DOS onto the pen drive it will boot from it.  However it then assigns C: to the pen drive and the other flash doesn't seem to appear anywhere as a drive (can't see it with dir D:, dir E:, etc)

Answer (score 3):

[Super User Blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com/utilities/portable-usb-flash-drive-toolkit) to the rescue!  You can use [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to create a boot-able flash drive and it even has an entry for Windows rescue disks (I understand that a rescue disk is different than a install, but the boot entries *should* be the same). If that entry fails however you can utilize the "unlisted" iso entry in PenDriveLinux.  You'll have to edit the GRUB menu yourself but that's not extremely difficult.  [Here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/925285) is a good place to start looking (last post).

Answer (score 2):

After [looking at the hardware specs](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=420579&prodTypeId=12454&objectID=c00209579), I don't think you can put another OS on it.

No hard drive, and no way to add one, only 32 or 128mb flash rom memory.

I converted a Wyse thin client to an XP box once, but it had an IDE controller on the motherboard, so I added a laptop hard drive to it, worked out nice.

Comment: Certainly it's beginning to look that way.  I put Win98 DOS onto a key and booted from that.  It booted and assigned key to C:, and FDISK only finds the C: drive.  I guess I'm stuffed.